# unix 'Tee' like behaviour for side effect + map in scala

Tags: scala

What's the Scala-idiomatic way to cause a side-effect *and* return an object? Currently I have

```
def fun: Future[Option[A]] = {
    val result = {// code returning a Future[Option[A]]}
    result.map{_.foreach(doSomething())}
    result
}
```

But I'm sure there's a nicer way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the idiomatic Scala way would be to use andThen, which is specifically for causing side effects.

```
def fun: Future[Option[A]] = {
    {// code returning a Future[Option[A]]}
    .andThen{_.foreach(doSomething())}       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Future.onComplete ([ScalaDoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future))

```
def fun: Future Future[Option[A]] = {
    val result = {// code returning a Future[Option[A]]}
    result.onComplete(r => doSomething())
    result
}
```